# AIDE application keeps crashing at start up. Anything wrong with code

Tags: java, android, aide-ide, aide

I will post code here.

I have developed a simple app using AIDE on my phone as opposed to Android Studio on PC. It is part of an Udemy course.

It keeps crashing when I click to run on AIDE.

When I click to run a pop up appears saying "This app may be harmful and may damage your device and data. We do not recommend you install this app"

I clicked to Install.

Moments later the app shuts down before anything appears with the message "Unfortunately MyApp had to be stopped".

Are there any problems with the code. I will post all java, XML and manifest code below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clipChildren="true"
android:padding="13dp">

<TextView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Bill Total"
android:visibility="visible"
android:alpha="1.0"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textColor="#6CE6E0"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:id="@+id/BillTotal"/>

<EditText
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<TextView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Tip Percentage"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingTop="12dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#63E4D6"
android:id="@+id/TipPercentage"/>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center">

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="10"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/Percent10"/>

<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="15"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/Percent15"/>

<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="20"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/Percent20"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Tip: $0.00"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#86DFE0"
android:id="@+id/TipTotal"/>

<TextView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Total: $0.00"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#87DFD6"
android:id="@+id/Total"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The main java code

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
TextView tipTotalTextView;
TextView totalTextView;
EditText billTotalEditView;
Button TenPercentButton;
Button FifteenPercentButton;
Button TwentyPercentButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

tipTotalTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TipTotal);
totalTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Total);
billTotalEditView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.BillTotal);
TenPercentButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Percent10);
FifteenPercentButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Percent15);
TwentyPercentButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Percent20);

TenPercentButton.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(android.view.View v){

Double TotalOfBill = Double.valueOf(billTotalEditView.getText().toString());

Double TotalTip = TotalOfBill * 0.1;

tipTotalTextView.setText("Tip: $"+TotalTip.toString());
Double total = TotalOfBill + TotalTip;
totalTextView.setText("Tip: $"+total.toString());


}
});

FifteenPercentButton.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(android.view.View v){

Double TotalOfBill = Double.valueOf(billTotalEditView.getText().toString());

Double TotalTip = TotalOfBill * 0.15;

tipTotalTextView.setText("Tip: $"+TotalTip.toString());
Double total = TotalOfBill + TotalTip;
totalTextView.setText("Tip: $"+total.toString());


}
});

TwentyPercentButton.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(android.view.View v){

Double TotalOfBill = Double.valueOf(billTotalEditView.getText().toString());

Double TotalTip = TotalOfBill * 0.2;

tipTotalTextView.setText("Tip: $"+TotalTip.toString());
Double total = TotalOfBill + TotalTip;
totalTextView.setText("Tip: $"+total.toString());



}
});
}

}
```

And the manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:resizeableActivity = "true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: *"It keeps crashing when I click to run on AIDE."*  - That is not an adequate problem description.  At least show us the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Run it again then when it crushes, go to aide-ide logcat and check the output.

You can configure the level to error so that it shows less info and check why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

When I click to run a pop up appears saying 
"This app may be harmful and may damage your device and data. We do not recommend you install this app"

I clicked to Install.

Moments later the app shuts down before anything appears with the message "Unfortunately MyApp had to be stopped".

Answer (score 0):

Change Build Varient To debug-aide. More>Projects>Build Varients.
Then Run Your App And See  Logcat  and note the error for crashing.

Are You using your own key to sign the app? Harmful Popup from playstore may be for this reason.